# Eclipse Juno with Java SE 7 Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-juno

I am trying to configure Eclipse Juno with Java SE 7
Here's my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/javaw.exe
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

I tried to change to -vm to `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin` and even tried to remove.

Still same error  `Failed to Create Java virtual machine.`

Using `Windows 7 x32 OS`.

I have both Java 6 SE and Java 7 SE for different purposes.

If i give -vm as `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6/bin` it's working fine.

What's the issue here. Path to JDK is fine.

I experimented little and found that

```
-Xmx800m
```

is the maximum amount I can set as -Xmx value. If i increase it beyond that, it's failing to create. Why is it so? Why JAVA 6 SE is able to do the same thing where as Java 7 SE unable to do. My project is huge. I hit Eclipse 1.4Gb memory sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you are trying to launch Juno with Java 7 JVM?  Can you not just add/configure the java 7 jdk/jre in the JRE Preferences of Juno (ie: Preferences->JRE) and use it that way?  Or do you have a specific reason why you are trying to launch it with java 7?

Comment: I just wanted to give a try and see if any performance improvements from Eclipse

Comment: If you are having performance issues with Juno, you are not alone.  A lot of people are having significant slower responses with Juno that with Indigo.  Take a look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272.  It may be related to your issues as well.

Comment: Certainly we can't expect Juno to give same speed as Indigo as soon as it's released. But point is, they are very slow at updating eclipse which is causing lot of headache for Java developers. I wish we can have solid IDE like Visual Studio

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't even attempt to compare VisualStudio with Eclipse as they are in two different worlds.  That being said, if you are having so many problems with Juno, then revert to Indigo.

Comment: Just in case if I missed out, Juno 4.2 SR1 is next official release for Eclipse 4 with bug fixes right. I can see the date is passed few days back. Am i seeing something wrong or is it released?

Comment: Not sure.  I know they are hoping to get some of these performance issues pushed into SR2, but I don't know if they will make it.  To be honest, I stopped using Juno once I saw how slow it was compared to Indigo, and am waiting for them to be resolved before I try again.

Comment: I think SR1 released silently
http://eclipse.org/downloads/
http://jdevelopment.nl/eclipse-42-sr1-silently-released/

Answer (score 0):

Try `-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/javaw.exe`. By default, Eclipse launcher uses jvm.dll, which provides some benefits (like Eclipse icon in the task bar), but DLLs on Windows are subject to memory fragmentation. Different DLLs on your system are pinned into different locations. This can present a problem as the amount you specify via -Xmx must be contiguous or JVM will not start.

The ultimate fix is to switch to a 64-bit version of Windows. Even if you don't have a lot of physical memory, the bigger virtual address space will make memory fragmentation not an issue.

Comment: Even that has thrown Error unless I decrease MaxSize to 800M. But real question why it's not an issue with Java 6 SE

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to edit eclipse.ini,if you want config eclipse to java 7, try this simple thing.
In System variables  set the path such that java 7 should come first as 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin;.;C:\Program Files.........